# What's the proper bitsize for int_fastN_t on different bitness platforms?

Tags: c++

As we all know, `stdint.h` offers both data and code-economic variants for some N-bit type by `int_leastN_t` and `int_fastN_t`, respectively. I suppose it does it with `word` size in mind for different CPU's.
That being said and from what I know, a 64-bit CPU processes 64-bit data faster than less-bit data, whatever "less" is. It logically follows that 64-bit integer is faster than 32-bit and when it comes to 64-bit CPU's, using a 16-bit data as fast as possible, `int_fast16_t` would have `INT_FAST16_MIN` defined to `INT64_MIN` instead of the `INT32_MIN` specified in `stdint.h`.
A similar case would be `int_fast8_t`for 32-bit CPU's but the catch is `char` is *exactly* 8 bits, regardless, so there can't be a *least* version.

I know current specification has to accommodate both 64-bit and 32-bit processors but theoretically, from 64-bit pov, would my statement be correct?

Comment: Why don't you just use sizeof() to get the size of type?

Comment: You mean `cstdint`, hopefully. `stdint.h` is deprecated.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Comment: A 64 bit processor is more accurately defined by the ability to process a 64 bit number in **less than twice** the time it needs for 32 bit vars. The time per bit decreases, but total time might increase. Even is each instruction in isolation would be equally fast, 32 bits vars still would be faster overall by using less cache space.

Comment: @E_net4: that link shows they're the same; still, if I'm correct, at least on my PC cstdint does nothing else but "wraps" stdint.h. what are the differences then?

Comment: @MSalters: AFAIK there are cases of n-bit CPU multiplying (n/2)-bit vars: it has to fill the (n/2)-bit data to format it to n-bit, make the operation then truncate it back to (n/2)-bit for RAM.

Comment: @mireazma The point I mentioned isn't critical. Besides being deprecated, I think the contents are declared in the global namespace instead of std. Since I suppose you are free to choose cstdint instead, I gave you the advice of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no general theoretical basis for determining how `[u]int_fastN_t` should be defined, apart from the obvious requirement that they must be at least `N` bits wide.

There's really no firm definition of what a "32-bit" or "64-bit" CPU is. The number might refer to the size of a general-purpose CPU register, or to the size of an address, or to the width of some internal bus, or to the whim of the marketing department. There have been a number of CPUs whose "bitness" has been vague; some CPUs have been 8-bit in some ways and 16-bit on others, or 16-bit and 32-bit. See the evolution of the x86 and 68k CPU families for examples.

It's entirely possible to have a CPU with 64-bit general-purpose registers that also has instructions that can perform 32-bit arithmetic faster than 64-bit arithmetic. For that matter, 64-bit addition might be faster than 32-bit addition, and 32-bit division faster than 64-bit division.

Personally, I'm content to let the compiler and runtime library implementers worry about it, and define the `[u]intfastN_t` types in the most reasonable way for the targeted architecture. If I need to know the actual size at run time, there's always the `sizeof` operator. If I need to know the actual size when I'm writing code, I probably shouldn't be using `[u]int_fastN_t` in the first place.

Here's what the C standard says about the `[u]int_leastN_t` types ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.20.1.3:

> Each of the following types designates an integer type that is usually
>   fastest to operate with among all integer types that have at least the
>   specified width.
>
> The typedef name **`int_fastN_t`** designates the fastest signed integer
>   type with a width of at least **`N`**. The typedef name **`uint_fastN_t`**
>   designates the fastest unsigned integer type with a width of at least
>   **`N`**.
>
> The following types are required:
>   **`int_fast8_t`**  **`uint_fast8_t`**
>   **`int_fast16_t`** **`uint_fast16_t`**
>   **`int_fast32_t`** **`uint_fast32_t`**
>   **`int_fast64_t`** **`uint_fast64_t`**
>   All other types of this form are optional.

There are the only guarantees offered by the C standard; anything beyond that is non-portable.

Comment: Thanks for explaining; about CPU bitness, there has to be a general rule, otherwise `int_fast16_t`wouldn't exist to begin with, defined with (note!) minimum 32-bit size.  I may be wrong about 64-bit CPU handling data bitnesses of 16-bit or less -- this is exactly what I'm interested in -- but I'm surely not wrong about 32-bit CPU with 16-bit data, due to `int_fast16_t`.  I think the matter can _also_ hold true for up a level (64-bit CPU with 32-bit data).  About `sizeof`: what use would it be?

Comment: @mireazma: You assert that `int_fast16_t` has a minimum size of 32 bits. What is your basis for that assumption? See my update, citing the C standard.

Comment: @mireazma: "*About `sizeof`: what use would it be?*" -- You asked about the sizes of the `int_leastN_t` types. `sizeof` will tell you their sizes.